# AWS Glue - JDBC Connection test failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm starting with AWS Glue, and want to connect to my on premise mysql server via JDBC.

I follow the documentation, create for glue the IAM Role, policy, security group and connection with correct jdbc connection string.
But when I test the connection I receive the following CloudWatch records:

```
"Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with 
correct URL syntax, username, and password. Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The 
driver has not received any packets from the server.

Exiting with error code 30"
```

I'm pretty sure the jdbc connection string is correct.

Something in the Glue config must be missing or wrong.

Comment: Can you check if you have configured the security group and JDBC connection properly.Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html and if every thing looks intact as in doc then try launching a ec2 machine from the subnet where you are creating the connection and test the connection between ec2 and your database

Comment: By onpremise mysql server, do you mean it is running in your private network and not in AWS environment?

Comment: yes Harsh, exactly that way. My private network and not AWS environment. The database is publicy available.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs normally in the following scenarios:

1. When the the VPC in question is used for the VPN configuration.
2. When the security group is not configured correctly. for instance you have to whitelist  these IPs for AWS
   52.92.16.0/20
   52.216.0.0/15
   54.231.0.0/17
3. When the IAM role for group is not configured correctly.
4. When you are using glue to connect to an on premise
   Your case could be among these.
   Follow this link from [AWS][1]
   [1]: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/

Comment: While this is true, it would be great if you could add some information on how to fix those points or links to the corresponding documentation

Answer (score -6):

Please check the JDBC url with the port :5439/database name. It should work fine